# $v_2$ is not substitutable for $v_1$ in $\forall \,v_1\,\forall\,v_2\,Bv_1v_2\to\forall v_2 Bv_2v_2$

Tags: logic, axioms, substitution

Definitions: Let $\alpha$ be a formula, $x$ be a variable and $t$ be a term. We say that **$t$ is substitutable for $x$** in $\alpha$ as follows:

> $(1)$ For atomic $\alpha, t$ is always substitutable for $x$ in
>   $\alpha.$
>
> $(2)$ $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $(\neg \alpha)$ iff $t$ is
>   substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha.$
>
> $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $(\alpha\to\beta)$ iff $t$ is
>   substitutable for $x$ in both $\alpha$ and $\beta.$
>
> $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\forall y\,\alpha$ if and only if
>   either
>
> (a) $x$ does not occur free in $\forall y\,\alpha,$ or
>
> (b) $y$ does not occur in $t$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in
>   $\alpha.$

We say that **$x$ occurs free in $\forall v_i\,\alpha$** if and only if $x$ occurs free in $\alpha$ and $x\neq v_i.$

**Axiom group $2$** contains formula of the form 
$$\forall x\,\alpha\to\alpha^x_t$$
where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha.$

I am reading Enderton's logic book and have reached substitutability. The author stated the following:

> $$\forall \,v_1\,\forall\,v_2\,Bv_1v_2\to\forall v_2 Bv_2v_2$$
>   is not in axiom group $2,$ since $v_2$ is not substitutable for $v_1$ in $\forall\, v_2 Bv_1v_2.$

However, I could not reach the same conclusion as the author.
The following is my verification.

We let 
$$x=v_1, \alpha=\forall v_2\,Bv_1v_2, t=v_2.$$

$v_1$ does not occur free in $\forall v_1\,\alpha$ since $v_1$ has a quantifier attached to it. 
So $v_2$ is substitutable for $v_1$ in $$\forall \,v_1\,\forall\,v_2\,Bv_1v_2\to\forall v_2 Bv_2v_2.$$

What's wrong with my verification?

Comment: Your definition above is not complete, you need a criteria to tell when $t$ is sustitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is not a of the form $\forall y \beta$. Otherwise you can't verifypart $b)$ of your definition is satisfied

Comment: @laflaca: I have typed the complete definition of subsitutability.

Comment: We are violating part (b). We have $t := v_2$ and $x := v_1$. But the formula is of type $\forall y \alpha$, where $y$ is $v_2$. The clause says: "$y$ (i.e. $v_2$) does not occur in $t$ (again: $v_2$)".

Comment: Also note that what you need to verify is that $v_2$ is sustitutable for $v_1$ in $\alpha$ (the same $\alpha$ you defined above), not in the whole implication in order to conclude that implication is in axiom group 2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I do not understand why $y$ is $v_2.$ I thought $y$ is $v_1,$ as it appears in the leftmost quantifier?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that's not the part of b) that is being violeted. The problem is that $v_2$ is not sustitutable for $v_1$ in  $\forall v_2 Bv_1v_2$ as the author of the book stated

Comment: The axiom is $\forall x \alpha \to \alpha_t^x$. The formula is $∀v_1 ∀v_2 
 Bv_1 v_2 \to ∀v_2 B v_2 v_2$. Thus $\forall x$ is $∀v_1$ and $\alpha$ is $∀v_2 Bv_1 v_2$ and we have to check that $v_2$ is *substitutable* for $v_1$ into $∀v_2 Bv_1 v_2$ (i.e. $\alpha$) in order to produce $\alpha_t^x$ i.e. $(∀v_2 Bv_1 v_2)_{v_2}^{v_1}$.

Comment: In your reading, we have $α=∀v_2 B v_1 v_2$ and you are saying that (a) applies because $v_1$ (i.e. $x$) is **not** free in $\forall v_1 \alpha$. But we have to check the subsitutibility into $\alpha$, i.e. $∀v_2 B v_1 v_2$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Now I see your argument. Yes, $v_1$ does occur freely. But to show that $v_2$ is not substitutable for $v_1,$ we need to make sure both (a) and (b) do not hold right?

Answer (score 1):

In your example let $\alpha=Bv_1v_2$, $t=v_2$ and $x=v_1$ and apply your definition.
$t$ is not sustitutable for $x$ in $\forall t Bxt$ because of part $a)$ of your definition, i.e $x$ is free in $\forall t Bxt$

EDIT: let now
$$x=v_1, \alpha=\forall v_2\,Bv_1v_2, t=v_2.$$ as you did before. Whe're trying to prove that $t$ is sustitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$.

Condition $a)$ is satisfied as you verified, but condition $b)$ is not because of the first part of this post, i.e $v_2$ is not sustitutable for $v_1$ in $\forall v_2\,Bv_1v_2$

Comment: Yes. I know that $t$ is not substitutable for $x$ in $\forall\, tBxt.$ But before verifying it, shouldn't we verify the outer part, that is, $\forall x\,\forall t Bxt\to \forall t Btt ?$

Comment: You're right, I'll edit